# ASP.NET Membership Error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-membership

I'm using ASP.NET MVC. I inserted ASP.NET membership tables into my database and i'm getting the error written below. Solution maybe? Thanks.

> The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'.  However, the current database schema is not compatible with this version.  You may need to either install a compatible schema with aspnet_regsql.exe (available in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a newer version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you run the aspnet_regsql.exe file?

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe

I've done this countless times and never got that error. Try doing that.

EDIT:

[alt text http://img529.imageshack.us/img529/9678/schema.png](http://img529.imageshack.us/img529/9678/schema.png)

Also [take a look at this](http://forums.asp.net/p/985097/1267872.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean, did that fix it?

Comment: Also, make sure you restart your website for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure the "aspnet_SchemaVersions" table exists in your database
2. Make sure it contains an entry for each "feature" you are using.  The aspnet scripts *should* do this for you.
3. Check your security (connection string) to see if you have the right to select from that table, exec the procs, etc. from the web app.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the replies.  These articles are very helpful.  I figured out the problem though and it was a typical bonehead mistake.  I used a script to recreate all the tables for Membership.  I didn't copy any data into those tables.  There is a table called aspnet_schemaversions.  It requires some values to be able to validate the versions (duh).  When I added these values into the table, it started working.

common 1 1
health monitoring 1 1
membership 1 1
personalization 1 1
profile 1 1
role manager 1 1

Comment: This is absolutely the answer

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I had a different solution:

In my connection strings in the `web.config`, I had `Persist Security Info=True;` included. Removing this solved my schema error,

> The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database
>   schema compatible with schema version '1'.