# Publishing to IIS7 with custom MemberShipProvider gives error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, web-config, asp.net-membership

I've built a website with MVC3, .Net 4.0, and I'm trying to get it to work on my test server. The server is a default installation of win2008 r2.

While testing and debugging (with the ASP.Net development server) the site works just fine. When I publish the site to my server, the site works fine, until I press submit on my login form. The error I get is found below.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http:// schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http:// schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http:// schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 36:       <providers>
Line 37:         <clear/>
Line 38:         <add name="CovleUserProvider" type="FileUpload.Models.CovleMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="UserInfo" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
Line 39:       </providers>
Line 40:     </membership>
```

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config    Line: 38

Some side info:
The name and namespace of the membership provider is correct (it works on the dev machine), The membership provider is part of the web project, but it references dll's from other projects. All references are there in the bin folder.

What I've tried:
Trust level is on full.
I shouldn't have to reference my own assemblies in the web.config (as far as I can tell from online resources)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like your `aspnet_SchemaVersions` is empty, here is screenshot of what it should look like

[image]

PS this question may also help you [ASP.NET Membership Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916787/asp-net-membership-error)

Comment: Apparently I was completely unaware that a database should exist at all purely for the use of ASP.Net applications. but I found out where and what and now I'm all set up. Thank you!