# Error with Membership CreateUser

Tags: asp.net, web-config, roles, membership

I am creating a new user programmatically (will be adding custom profiles later) and am working on Win2K8 VM:

```
MembershipUser newUser = 
    Membership.CreateUser(userNameTxt.Text, passwordTxt.Text, emailTxt.Text);
Roles.AddUserToRole(userNameTxt.Text.Trim(), "Member");
```

**UPDATE:**

Connection string:

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
<add name="LocalSqlServer" 
    connectionString="Initial Catalog=MYS;Data Source=WIN2K8;uid=MYS;password=xxxxxx;"   
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Getting the following error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MYAPP'.

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <remove name="DefaultMembershipProvider"/>
        <add 
            name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
            enablePasswordReset="false" 
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
            requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
            minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
            passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
            applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
```

Comment: would like to see your connection string. sometimes this happens when you use integrated security. have you tried using giving username, password in connection string?

Comment: No, I haven't. I added connection string to question.

Comment: could you try not giving integrated security and give username password instead? ( sql login )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current connection string is this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
    connectionString="Initial Catalog=MYS;Data Source=WIN2K8;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The error here is that you're saying: *Connect to my SQL Server database and use the App Pool identity as the 'account' to authenticate my SQL Server db against.*

All websites on IIS run under an 'account'. In this case, it looks like this account is called `MyApp`.

So the fix you need to have a connection string that says: Don't use whatever 'identity' is setup on this IIS machine, etc. BUT! Use this hardcoded username/password instead.

Check this out, now:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
    connectionString="Initial Catalog=MYS;Data Source=WIN2K8;uid=username;password=pass;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Take note:

1. I've removed the argument: `Integrated Security=SSPI;`
2. I've added the argument: `uid=username;`
3. I've added the argument: `password=pass;`

Just replace the values `username` and `pass` with the username/password you use to log into your SQL Server database.

Need help learning about what options/keywords you can define in a single connection string? [Check this ConnectionStrings site as a reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Pro Tip: Instead of `<remove name="whatever/>` .. try using `<clear/>`

eg.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Initial Catalog=MYS;Data Source=WIN2K8;uid=username;password=pass;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: When I add <clear /> I get: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Comment: *le sigh* ... please note .. that the `<clear/>` has to come -before- the `<add ..>`. Why? this says : get rid of -any and all- of the default connections strings ... and now ADD my own. And i'll call it `LocalSqlServer`.

Comment: I put it in place of the old remove which was before the add... probably just a side issue anyway.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then don't use the Pro tip. Secondly, check the spelling of the `<add>` .. making sure the `name=XXX` is exactly what is being used in the `connectionstrings` and `membership provider`.

Comment: Got this connection format to work on my server (but not on my local WIN2K8 VM). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It works on the remote server because that remote server has a locked down IIS, etc. You always need to provide the sql server LOGIN/USER details on a Hosting server which you didn't make. On your -own- local server .. u can use `Integrated Security=SSPI` because that is your own machine and you've logged in as 'YOURSELF' so anything that runs will run 'as you'. There is no 'logged in user' on a remote server. Dude - I really recommend you read up a little bit about basic IIS authentication and what `Integrated Security=SSPI` actually really means.

Comment: I understand that under my own logged-in name it should have worked but it didn't. I suspected it had to be something else and that turned out to be the case. The aspnet_SchemaVersions table had no data. Thanks for your help Pure, much appreciated.

Comment: Pleasure :) gl! (For the record: Avoid ASP.NET Membership like the plague. Worst thing in the framework, after Entity Framework).

Answer (score 1):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MYAPP'.

This indicates that your application pool identity is the virtual account 'IIS APPPOOL\MYAPP'.

You need create a SQL Server login for this identity and add it as a User with appropriate permissions to the Membership database.

> Not sure what you mean by create a SQL Server login for "this identity" ...

One way is to use SQL Server Management Studio.  Connect "Object Explorer" to your SQL Server instance, click right on "Security / Logins" , select "New Login" and add the login name IIS APPPOOL\MYAPP with Windows Authentication.

Then map this login to a user in the Membership database.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by create a SQL Server login for "this identity" - add DB user with same name as my app?

Answer (score 0):

Check with your connection string it should be as shown:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Regarding your modified error:

Set **enableEventValidation** to false and **viewStateEncryptionMode** to Never as follows:

```
<pages enableeventvalidation="false" viewstateencryptionmode="Never">
```

Comment: Not using SQLEXPRESS, am using SQL server and connection string is working.

Comment: you can find it more detail from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx and from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx

Comment: Gives 500.19 error and squiglies in config file saying these attributes are not allowed. Am using ASP.NET 4.5 in VS2012.

Comment: Try to watch this video where you need to install some components and then it works fine http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBNoTK31zPo or follow this SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0

Comment: Will do. I added those two properties in the page directive but still got the App Pool error. Thanks for your help, I'll watch the video :)

Comment: you're welcome hope that helps you in solving your problem :)

Comment: Maybe should have said I am developing on Win2K8 VM

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the connection problem by populating the aspnet_SchemaVersions table, per this link:

[ASP.NET Membership Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916787/asp-net-membership-error)

I was then able to connect locally thus:

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
    connectionString="Initial Catalog=MYS;Data Source=WIN2K8;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```